# replacing wiki markups with HTML tags using regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have been given several text documents that are formatted with wiki markups (==, ===, --, --, # etc), and i have to reformat them with HTML tags (–, —,<> etc)  instead. now it has to return True if it formatted successfully, and False if it didnt. This is what i have so far:

```
def wiki_markup ():
    for () in range ()
    sub('--', '&ndash;')
    sub('---', '&mdash;')
    sub('''(.+)''', '<i>(.+)</i>')
    sub("'''(.+)'''", '<b>(.+)</b>')
    sub("==(.+)==", "<h1>(.+)</h2>")
    sub("#(.+)#", "<li>(.+)</li>")
    sub("*(.+)*","<li>(.+)</li>")
```

Now i know i need to put in code that goes along the lines of if it was successful then print true, if else then print false, but i'm honestly stuck at this part. I also don't even know if what i've done so far is on the right track. i'll post an example of what im trying to reformat:

> == Early years ==
>
> Rachel Chiesley was one of ten children born to John Chiesley of [[Dalry, Edinburgh|Dalry]] and Margaret Nicholson. The
>   marriage was unhappy and Margaret took her husband to court for
>   [[alimony]]. She was awarded 1,700 [[Merk (coin)| merks]] by [[George
>   Lockhart (advocate)| Sir George Lockhart of Carnwath]], the [[Lord
>   President of the Court of Session]]. Furious with the result,  John
>   Chiesley shot Lockhart dead on the [[Royal Mile]] in [[Edinburgh]] as
>   he walked home from church on [[Easter Sunday]], 31 March 1689.{{Sfn |
>   Macaulay | 2009 | pp = 23–24}}  The assailant made no attempt to
>   escape and confessed at his trial, held before the [[Lord Provost]]
>   the next day. Two days later he was taken from the [[Heart of
>   Midlothian (Royal Mile)|Tolbooth]] to the Mercat Cross on the High
>   Street. His right hand was cut off before he was hanged, and the
>   pistol he had used for the murder was placed round his neck.{{Sfn |
>   Macaulay | 2009 | pp = 29–30}}  Rachel Chiesley's birthday is unknown
>   but she was baptised on 4 February 1679 and was probably born shortly
>   before then, making her about ten years old at the time of her
>   father's execution.{{Sfn | Macaulay | 2009 | p = 19}}

It should come out with certain words in boldtext where it's tagged etc etc.

can anyone help?

Comment: I advise you to learn Python first. [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) is the official tutorial and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) are the docs for the regex library.

Comment: Have you considered using [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for this purpose?  I'm not sure if it has Python bindings available, though.

Comment: @devnull: Does MarkDown support Wiki syntax? I don't think they are the same thing.